# Transform scaleY makes border bottom appear

Tags: css

I have this button that I'd like to make it appear like a previously accessed link. To make that I need to apply a scale transform, however, when I do that, there is a border that appears that doesn't look good.

[This is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markens/9neeavk3/4/)

```
#contact button {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #387d89;
    font-size: 9.84px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background: #245963;
    /*-webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);*/
}
```

I've commented out the CSS that does the scaling, that is what I need to apply without border bottom of #contact button appearing.

I hope you can understand what I need..Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @theWanderer4865 to help me :)

Comment: Do you mean the blue border?

Comment: Yes, the blue border that appears on top of the triangle when I scale the button @alirezasafian

Answer (score 2):

Add outline: none; to this rule #contact button.

```
#contact button {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #387d89;
    font-size: 9.84px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background: #245963;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1); 
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);

    /* outile */
    outline: none;        
}
```

Comment: @markens Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/9neeavk3/6/)

Comment: `#contact button:focus { outline: none; }`

Comment: not working either..Is it possible to put a link to style, inside the button?

Comment: @markens Canu upload the screenshot of the blue border? What is your browser?

Comment: This is how it looks (http://i.imgur.com/Zv5Pdr7.jpg) I use Chrome, but I also checked in Firefox and looks the same.

Comment: @markens Because the border color does not match the background color. This is fixed [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/9neeavk3/7/)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want these colors to match, I need another border-color for the border different from the background. Never mind, I will remove the scaleY transform and it will be ok, thanks @alirezasafian